# Что делает `git branch -M main` в Git?

Tags: git

Что делает `git branch -M main` в Git?

Comment: там вверху ↑ поиск есть: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66673759/git-branch-m-main

Comment: То на английском же

Comment: шел 22 год 21 века, люди впервые слышали про онлайн переводчики... 
Далеко не уедете без знания английского на уровне чтения документации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открываем доку https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch и читаем

```
-M
Shortcut for --move --force.
```

То есть это просто заменяет эти два параметра. Первый параметр помогает переименовать ветку, второй подавляет ряд "ошибок" - например, ветка существует.

Зачем нужна прям эта команда ? А это популярное сейчас переименование master в main, так как некоторым кажется, что master обидное. Ок, пусть будет.